# Angular and jasmine: how to avoid default route to test a specific route after clicking a button

Tags: angular, testing, routes, jasmine

I want to test a method that use a router to navigate to another page, the method's name is **goToView():**

```
  goToView(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['../'+this.view],{relativeTo:this.activeRoute})
  }
```

In my spec class I added this:

```
describe('HomeRedirectionBoxComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeRedirectionBoxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeRedirectionBoxComponent>;
  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeRedirectionBoxComponent],
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(appRoutes)],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeRedirectionBoxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(  () =>  {
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
     component.goToView();
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
  }));
});
```

The method which fails:

```
  it('should navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(  () =>  {
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
     component.goToView();
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
  }));
```

The error message:
[image]

The problem is that when I load my application first time, I have a redirection to "/homePage", bellow my AppRouteModule where I configure routes and redirections:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/homePage', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'homePage', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

export default appRoutes;
```

How can I set specific spy when only I click the goToView() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (follow comments with !!):

```
describe('HomeRedirectionBoxComponent', () => {
  let component: HomeRedirectionBoxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomeRedirectionBoxComponent>;
  let location: Location;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeRedirectionBoxComponent],
      //!! remove withRoutes, it is not necessary for the test to know about your routes
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeRedirectionBoxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should navigate to dashboard', fakeAsync(  () =>  {
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
    component.goToView();
    //!! get the first argument
    const firstArg = navigateSpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0];
    //!! expect ['../dashboard'] to contain 'dashboard'
    expect(firstArg[0]).toContain('dashboard');
  }));
});
```

Comment: Thank you this is so inspirational, also I discovered that I forget to set the view property of the component in the test method, your solution works perfectly, but for my case I had to set the view property just before calling the .goToView() method, by doing : component.view="dashboard"